Why is Windows 11 Pro seemingly disabling Windows Hello when using RDP?
I recently came into a situation where I had to move, and due to extenuating circumstances, I couldn't arrange to have my desktop PC with me immediately when I moved.
I have it connected to a Tailscale Tailnet, set up with a few methods of remotely accessing my machine, such as AnyDesk, Parsec, and I went through the effort of getting RDP set up in a way that's more secure (Access through the tailnet, on a non-standard port, local account with decent security.), allowing me to just simply RDP in from my laptop (Ubuntu running Remmina).
Everything works as I expect, I had been simply using parsec to do it for simplicity and also for better handling for gaming loads over a network, but switching to RDP for better handling of remote peripherals, such as my headset.
I noticed when using RDP, Windows Hello suddenly wasn't prompting me for things like they usually do or for unlocking my password manager on my remote machine (WinHello would handle that when I normally would use my computer), alongside my hardware security key management (FIDO tends to go through WinHello before the device itself for smartcard/security key management.)
I tried looking this behavior up online, and seen plenty trying to disable it so they could RDP to a local account, but that isn't my issue; I want Windows Hello enabled for it's utility, but seemingly, it has disappeared as an option. I know a bunch of stuff is disabled when a "remote connection is being used" (airquotes because it's only for RDP and the like), is Windows Hello one of them? I've seen posts regarding Windows Hello for Business, I assume that's getting into the enterprise-editions of Windows, but I am just simply running Windows 11 Pro (v23H2, b22631.4169). Is this something I just need to configure with Remmina, is it intentionally disabled for RDP connections, and is there any methods/documentation for ensuring that Windows Hello remains available over RDP connections?

Windows Hello isn’t responsible for UAC prompts. There are many components of Windows Hello (Biometrics, Pin, etc) what were you using specifically?

Specifically PIN and hardware key/FIDO support provided by hello.

This FIDO device requires a physical button press I assume? What RDP client are you using. I know TeamViewer supports USB pass through so as long as you have the device with you, and the remote client is configured to use that device, you should be able to authenticate remotely.

Originally the post reflected this, but Remmina. This is less though I think about the specific client, and moreso it seems when using RDP protocol to connect over a userland remote access tool (Teamviewer/Anydesk/etc), it disables various OS functionality, apparently including windows hello, which isn't documented as far as I can tell to have such a behavior.
To be explicitly clear, I prefer to use RDP if at all possible, but I am looking for more info about why Windows Hello is behaving like this, when by all accounts from my google-fu, isn't actually supposed to happen.

I simultaneously looked up Remmina then asked you which RDP. I suppose my real question is does Remmina support USB pass through? In my experience TeamViewer does not disable Windows Hello but I don’t use FIDO devices just a pin.

It does and doesn't? Like they have USB pass through called USB redirect, and it just mounts devices with the given lsusb ID or something, documentation isn't the greatest. However that again, may not be relevant because the whole windows hello subsystem is disabled. Like I can't use it for PIN either, which for example is one of the ways I can unlock my password manager (authenticate via winhello). This is less a question of "how do I direct my RDP client to forward my security key", it's more a "why is winhello completely disabled over RDP and is there any way of restoring it"

To clarify more, USB redirection in remmina is present and is intended for storage mediums, and other devices (Any other USB periph) are not technically supported but are 100% possible to route through this. again, the issue at hand is less about issues there, but more on why on earth is WinHello getting disabled

I hate to sound like a broke record, since you likely made this clear in your question, but how did you determine Windows Hello was actually being disabled. In my experience, connecting over RDP, does not actually cause Windows Hello to be turned off.

Went to sign-in settings, all the options that were previously set up for this are completely missing, and my already-configured settings for it only work when I am not connected via RDP and connected over something like anydesk. I also use Enpass as a Password Manager, which natively supports WinHello for unlocking after master passwd is entered once, but if I go into the settings, it reports windows hello isn't enabled, Again only whilst using the RDP protocol. Trust me, I am just as confused because by all accounts it shouldn't be disabled; but it looks very evident that it is.

I have not exhaustively confirmed it is being disabled by specifically RDP, but to reiterate, If I remote over outside of using RDP, by just using AnyDesk/Teamvwr, WinHello behaves normally, but when connecting specifically over RDP, all options related to WinHello are gone, my preexisting configuration no longer function, I don't get WinHello prompts when I usually would, and apps that have native support for WinHello aren't triggering it, like if I were to try signing in via my hardware seckey, it doesn't even show the winhello prompt, and I don't have any reason to believe this is remmina.
